# Move column in DataGridView without clicking on it twice

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Normally, to move a column in a `DataGridView`, you just click and drag. However, if you scroll immediately before this operation (which is quite common if you are moving columns), then you must click on the column before the click-and-drag. I thought this had something to do with the `DataGridView` losing focus, so I listened for `Scroll` events of type `EndScroll` from the horizontal scroll bar and called `Focus()` on the `DataGridView` there. That did not work. Does someone know how I can move columns without the extra click in this case?

Comment: Anyone? Any comments that might push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `WinForms` bug.

Decompiling `System.Windows.Forms` helped me to find the solution : declare a `DataGridView` child class and override the `OnScroll` function this way :

```
protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnScroll(e);
    base.OnMouseUp(new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, 0, 0, 0));
}
```